# Unable to install AMD driver on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, dell, amd-graphics, inspiron

I am trying to install AMD Radeon driver - fglrx on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, using the command `sudo apt-get install fglrx` but I am getting the following error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
fglrx : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                xorg-video-abi-15 or
                xorg-video-abi-18 or
                xorg-video-abi-19
        Depends: xserver-xorg-core
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output from `lspci -vvnn | grep VGA`

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg-query -l xserver-xorg-core\* | grep ^ii` and `apt-get install -sf fglrx xserver-xorg-core`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove hardware stack:

I will try to explain this in a way others can understand it - not so much an exact technical outline of why and how each thing works.

By default apt-get uses --install-recommends to get packages and dependencies. However there are times this fails to install things because it improperly tries to recommend things based on what it see's already installed on the system - especially when dealing with drivers (for example when the manufacture driver does not work as well as an open source one).

What this first command does (basically) is forces apt-get to do a recommended installed of a series of packages required for fglrx to work properly. By doing a recommended install you are basically "removing the hardward stack of drivers" and forcing a replacement with the recommended packages (this is not the same as an update or an uninstall/reinstall of drivers).

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1-mesa-drivers
```

Clean up extra packages:

This will basically go through the packages and clean up any packages that are just lingering and no longer needed (left overs from what we did above)

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Properly install:

This should correctly install with the proper hardware dependency stack.

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Don't forget to reboot.

Why do I recommend this as the solution - reminds me of an old bug from a couple years ago.. and the logs look strikingly familiar. you could probably find a bug with those exact logs in bug tracker records.

Comment: Could you please explain (shortly) what these commands are supposed to do? Why *two* Apt install commands and why the autoremove command? A plain command sequence is not usually considered an answer on AskUbuntu. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: Sorry David I usually try to give a bit more details. Not sure what I was thinking... must have been sleeping on the job. I will definitely make sure that doesn't happen again.

Comment: Thanks so far. Why do you suggest *two* Apt install commands and why the autoremove command?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Hopefully this now covers it. :)

Comment: I'm sorry that I was a bit unclear. I know what these commands do and wanted to question your reasons to 1) suggest to separate install commands when one would do (merging the lists of packages to install) 1) or to include the autoremove command at all because it's entirely unrelated to the installation of new packages.